# how to convert into simple string from soapBody.getPayloadSource()

Tags: java, security, soap, owasp, xxe

i want to try converting soapbody object to simple string xml using transformer
but its give me **XML entity injection (xxe)**

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();

StringWriter writerSoapBody = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(soapBody.getPayloadSource(), new StreamResult(writerSoapBody));
xmlString = writerSoapBody.getBuffer().toString();
```

its give me exception of xxe vulnerability, when i resolve with added two more properties like:-

> tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
>               tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");

then its give me other exception like

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD

**so my point is :-**

> 1.) Is there available other way to convert soapBody.getPayloadSource() into simple string ?
>
> 2.) why its give me error?

i reffer https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4435 for resolve xxe problem.

Thanks